# Prove that, $\mathbb{E}(F_1(X_1)) + \mathbb{E}(F_2(X_2)) = 1 + \mathbb{P}(X_1 = X_2)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value

$X_1$ and $X_2$ any two independent random variable with CDF $F_1(\cdot)$ and $F_2(\cdot)$. My question is when we do not know about the type of random variable, then
$$\mathbb{E}(F_1(X_1)) + \mathbb{E}(F_2(X_2)) =  1 + \mathbb{P}(X_1 = X_2)$$

Now, this is trivial if $X_1$ and $X_2$  are continuous random variables. Then
$$
F_i(X_i) \stackrel{d}{=} U_i \sim uniform[0,1]
$$
Then
$$
\mathbb{E}(F_1(X_1)) + \mathbb{E}(F_2(X_2)) =\\
\mathbb{E}(U_1) + \mathbb{E}(U_2) = 1
$$
But how to extend this result?

Comment: Are you sure this is correct in general? Suppose $P(X_1 = 0 ) = P(X_1 = 1 ) = 1/2$, and $P(X_2 = 1/4) = P(X_2 = 3/4) = 1/2$. Then $P(F_i(X_i) = 1/2)=P(F_i(X_i) = 1)=1/2$, so the left hand side is 1.5. But $P(X_1 = X_2) = 0$. Are you supposed to flops $X_1$ and $X_2$ in the left hand side?